# How can solve this program by switch case in c programming?

Tags: c

```c
int i=0, marks,pass=0, fail=0;
int A_Plus=0,A=0,A_minus=0,B_Plus=0,B =0,B_minus=0,C_Plus=0,C=0,C_minus=0,D_Plus=0,D=0,F=0;

while(marks !=-1)
{
    scanf("%d", &marks);
    if(marks<-1 || marks>100)
    {
        printf("You enter invalid mark: %d \n",marks);
    }
    if (marks != -1 &&(marks>=0 && marks <=100))
    {

        if(marks < 60)
        {
            fail = fail + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            pass = pass + 1;
        }
        i=i+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Afaik You can't

Comment: You can't. `switch` requires a single value for each `case`. It is not possible to specify ranges or conditions like `<60` in standard C.

Comment: In order to transform that if in a switch case you will need to write at least 60 cases inside switch and one default case.

Comment: Technically you *could* do `case 1: case 2: case 3: ... case 59:`.  But obviously you shouldn't.

Comment: This is not a good use case for a `switch` statement.  If you have to check against a range of values, you are better off using `if` statements (as you've done here).

Comment: With around 12 grades, you could use an array of marks needed for each, and another array of the grade names, and a loop.

Comment: You may benefit as well from breaking some of these checks out into separate functions. For instance: `int is_valid_grade(int grade) { return grade >= 0 && grade <= 100; }` and `int is_passing_grade(int grade) { return is_valid_grade(grade) && grade >= 60; }`

Comment: Switch is best when you have larger number of condition to compare. In this case if-else is best.

Comment: I assume you want equivalent code? i.e. just pass/fail count, and the the `A_Plus` etc. are irrelevant to the question?  Remove them if that is the case, they are a distraction and causing people to answer a different question that that which you have asked.  If that is not the case, clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is some academic exercise rather than some useful design aim?  So I'll play the silly game.  Expanding on Adrian Mole's idea:

```
// Grade: 0 = fail
//        1 = pass
//    other = invalid input
int grade == marks > 100 ? 
             -marks : 
             marks /= 60 ;

switch( grade )
{
    case 0: fail++ ; break ;
    case 1: pass++ ; break ;
    default: 
        if( marks != -1) printf( "You enter invalid mark: %d \n", marks ) ;
}
```

Note in any case your original code can be simplified in any case:

```
if( marks == -1 ) // do nothing
else if( marks < -1 || marks > 100 ) printf( "You enter invalid mark: %d \n", marks ) ;
else if( marks < 60) fail++ ;
else pass++ ;
```

An "at face value" solution:

```
switch( marks )
{
    case -1 : break
    case 0: case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5: case 6: case 7: case 8: case 9:
    case 10: case 11: case 12: case 13: case 14: case 15: case 16: case 17: case 18: case 19:
    case 20: case 21: case 22: case 23: case 24: case 25: case 26: case 27: case 28: case 29:
    case 30: case 31: case 32: case 33: case 34: case 35: case 36: case 37: case 38: case 39:
    case 40: case 41: case 42: case 43: case 44: case 45: case 46: case 47: case 48: case 49:
    case 50: case 51: case 52: case 53: case 54: case 55: case 56: case 57: case 58: case 59:
        fail++ ; break ;

    case 60: case 61: case 62: case 63: case 64: case 65: case 66: case 67: case 68: case 69:
    case 70: case 71: case 72: case 73: case 74: case 75: case 76: case 77: case 78: case 79:
    case 80: case 81: case 82: case 83: case 84: case 85: case 86: case 87: case 88: case 89:
    case 90: case 91: case 92: case 93: case 94: case 95: case 96: case 97: case 98: case 100:
        pass++ ; break ;

    default: 
        printf( "You enter invalid mark: %d \n", marks ) ;
}
```

With this latter solution at least you could insert the grade breaks that the `Plus_A`, `A` variables hint at perhaps.  If you were to do that you should calculate the pass/fail count by adding the grade counts rather then incrementing for each grade case.

Moreover if you are to have multiple grades, do not have a separate variable for each one - use an array, then an enumeration to index the array:

```
int grade_count[12] = {0} ;

enum eGrade
{
    A_Plus, A, A_minus,
    B_Plus, B, B_minus,
    C_Plus, C, C_minus,
    D_Plus, D, F
} ;
```

Then you might have:

```
grade_count[B_Plus]++ ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Although I do **not** recommend using a `switch` statement for "yes/no"-type decisions, such as yours, you *could* convert your `if ... else` blocks into the following `switch` block:

```c
switch (marks/60) // If marks is less than 60, this expression will truncate to zero ...
{
    case 0:
        ++fail;
        break;
    default: // ... otherwise, we'll get here.
        ++pass;
        break;
}
```

Note that this assumes that you have previously ruled out negative numbers (as you have done).

---

This approach (dividing the 'switch variable' by a constant) can be useful when you have more than two possible outcomes, determined by adjacent, fixed-size ranges. For example, rather than just "fail" and "pass", you may have 4 different grades (ranges `0..29`, `30..59`, `60..89` and `90+`); in such a case, a `switch` such as the following may be a good approach:

```c
switch (marks/30)
{
    case 0: // < 30
        ++fail;
        break;
    case 1: // 30 thru 59
        ++poor;
        break;
    case 2: // 60 thru 89
        ++good;
        break;
    default: // >= 90
        ++excellent;
        break;
}
```

Comment: Not sure I see the advantage over `if (marks / 60 == 0) { fail += 1; } else { pass += 1; }`.

Comment: @ChrisDutton I don't see *any* advantage in this case. But, maybe it's a theoretical/semantic issue? I suppose, when there are more than two 'ranges' (0..30, 31..60, 61..90 and 91+), it could be a useful guideline?

Comment: Too be completely honest, I missed the _not_ in your "I do not recommend" doing this.

Comment: @Chris I made it big and bold. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you use gcc like compiler (gcc, clang etc) you can use the extension:

```
switch(marks)
{
    case 0 ... 59:
        fail = fail + 1;
        break;
    default:
        pass = pass + 1;
        break;
}
```

But it is not standard C

Comment: The input -1 is accepted as a loop terminator, so you need a case do nothing case for that.  Using that extension you could include a range for pass and use the default for the error input case rather than unnecessarily having a separate check.  After all it is not stated that only the pass/fail blocks are the subject of the switch/case.  I'd assume the whole mark processing block were to be included.

Comment: @Clifford it is an illustration of the `gcc` extension, not the solution. I believe ,it is quite obvious.

Comment: ok, it was not a criticism, just a suggestion.  I doubt it is that obvious to anyone who would ask this question; clearly they are novices.  Also it seems not obvious to some who have attempted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have only two cases (greater or less than 60), so a switch would just be more complex. If you have a case with more (e.g. A, B, C etc. letter grades), you'd have to map [0, 100] to [A, B, C, D, F] to give a code or an enum, then switch on that result. Making the mapping would be more complex than just using a series of if / else if / else statements, but if you want to do that anyway, a loop like this would work:

```
enum GRADE {
    GRADE_A,
    GRADE_B,
     ...
    GRADE_F,
    GRADE_COUNT,  // Not an actual grade.
};

...

GRADE grade = GRADE_F;  // default
int mark = /* comes from somewhere */
struct {
    GRADE grade;
    int lowest;
} grade_list[] = {
    { GRADE_A, 90 },
    { GRADE_B, 80 },
    { GRADE_C, 70 },
    { GRADE_D, 60 },
    { GRADE_F, 0 },
};
for (int grade_idx = 0;
    grade_idx < GRADE_COUNT;
    grade_idx++
) {
    if (marks >= grade_list[grade_idx].lowest) {
        grade = grade_list[grade_idx].grade
        break;
    }
}
switch (grade) {
case GRADE_A:
    ...
    break;
case ...:
    ...
    break;
case GRADE_F:
    ...
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this as-is, instead collect the total count and subtract off the failures or successes later

```c
// reject < 0 or > 100
...
    marks_total++;
    if (mark - 60 > 0) marks_passing++;
}
marks_failed = marks_total - marks_passing;
```

Comment: It might be a clever way to eliminate the if/else, but it is not a `switch`, so not an answer.

Comment: @Clifford certainly not a direct one, but there are already others meeting that with caveats towards this .. I find the best answers are often a little "don't do this, there's a better way!" and also suspect that the user is both new to C and experiencing an XY problem!

Comment: Perhaps.  I assumed this was an academic exercise or programming quiz type question rather than a "best way to solve this problem" question.  I may be wrong, it may just be a dumb question.